# Mule server debugging and understanding

Tags: architecture, mule

I have been working on Mule for the last 3 years. I am using relevant components of the mule for the relevant needs. As I Java programmer, I wanted to know the Mule Sever Architecture and how I can debug the Mule source code.

More specifically, I wanted to know how the Mule Context will be created, how the Mule message will be created, etc.

Can any one please guide me in this regard?

Comment: I want to have a understand the internals as well :), and actually downloading and debugging it is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no such guide is available. The documentation is the [code](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule).

You can reach to the community (including us, the core dev team) at the [Mule forums](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft) for specific questions, but as I said, sadly there is no public architecture overview at the moment.

Is perhaps a good moment to take notes while learning and share them?